# Dropdown Category form. Only show Sub-Categories

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to get a category dropdown working. I have a Custom Post Type called "podcast" and custom taxonomy called "podcast_category".

What i want to display, is a list of categories which are child's of "the-building-code".  Normally for posts, i would use Tax_query, but really struggling to figure this one out.

```
<form class="js-filter-form">
            <select name="categories" id="categories">
                <?php
                
                    $cat_args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'podcast',
                        'taxonomy' => 'podcast_category'
                    );

                    $categories = get_categories($cat_args); ?>
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach($categories as $cat) : ?>
                        <option class="js-filter-item" value="<?= $cat->term_id; ?>">
                            <?= $cat->name; ?>
                        </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the `parent` argument of `get_categories()` (or better yet, `get_terms()` to the ID of the `the-building-code` term. If you don't know the ID you'll need to retrieve that first:

```
<form class="js-filter-form">
    <select name="categories" id="categories">
        <?php
        $parent = get_term_by( 'slug', 'the-building-code', 'podcast_category' );
        $cat_args = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'podcast_category',
            'parent' => $parent->term_id,
        );

        $categories = get_categories($cat_args); ?>
        <option value="">All</option>
        <?php
        foreach($categories as $cat) : ?>
            <option class="js-filter-item" value="<?= $cat->term_id; ?>">
                <?= $cat->name; ?>
            </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Also note that there's no `post_type` argument for `get_categories()` or `get_terms()`, so I removed it.